# Cannot ssh to localhost

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to see if ssh is properly configured on Ubuntu 11.04:

```
  ashish@ubuntu:~$ ssh localhost
  ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
  ashish@ubuntu:~$
```

What do I do from here?

Comment: what is o/p if your runs pgrep sshd ?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server
```

It's most likely that the ssh server is not installed as only the client is installed by default.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure the SSHD is running, looks like it is not.

Try

```
service sshd start
```

I am not familiar with ubuntu, but this should work.

Comment: In Ubuntu **service ssh status** shows the ssh's status. If not started, then **service ssh start** helps.

Answer (score 0):

Bonus if you need to start the X server you run this:

```
 ssh -x <host>
```