# Cannot get body-parser to return anything

Tags: node.js, express, body-parser

I've read dussins of stackoverflow posts now but I can't get my bodyparser to work. In order to not complicate things I changed to the most simple thing I could imagine, which is the code below and involve just parsing one single route. Can anyone see a problem?

routes/login.js

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

router.get('/', (req, res) => {
        res.send('<form method="POST" action="'+ req.originalUrl +'"><input type="text" id="personalNumber" autocomplete="off"><input type="submit" value="Log in"></form>');
        res.end();
});

router.post('/', bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }), (req, res) => {
        console.log('personal', req.body, req.personalNumber, res.body, req.headers);
        res.send('personal', req.body, req.personalNumber, res.body, JSON.stringify(req.headers));
        res.end();
});

module.exports = router;
```

server.js simplified

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var login = require(__dirname + '/routes/login');
app.use('/login', login);

app.listen(80, () => {
        console.log('Listening on port 80');
});
```

Going to /login, typing anything in the input and submitting (triggering a post to /login) will give use the following console output:

```
Listening on port 80
personal {} undefined undefined { host: 'localhost',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '0',
  pragma: 'no-cache',
  'cache-control': 'no-cache',
  origin: 'http://localhost',
  'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
  accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  referer: 'http://localhost/login',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8,sv;q=0.6' }
```

Expected output would be for req.body to contain some information about the data from the form.

```
req.body = {
    personalNumber: 'inputData'
};
```

Comment: You should be more specific about what is happening. Demonstrate what the code does differently than you are expecting it to

Comment: does your console display your expected result in the command prompt?

Comment: ...or is [running on port 80](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947356/node-js-app-cant-run-on-port-80-even-though-theres-no-other-process-blocking-t) a problem?

Comment: Updated the question. I hope it helps to solve the mystery.

Answer (score 1):

> `body-parser` works properly when it is added in your main file before all the `routes`

So put the following code after creating the object of `express` in `server.js` file

```
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: false
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    router.urlencoded({ extended: false });
    router.use(bodyParser.json());
    router.get('/', (req, res) => {
            res.send('<form method="POST" action="'+ req.originalUrl +'"><input type="text" id="username" autocomplete="off"><input type="submit" value="Log in"></form>');
            res.end();
    });

    router.post('/', (req, res) => {
            console.log('personal', req.body, req.personalNumber, res.body, req.headers);
            res.send('personal', req.body, req.personalNumber, res.body, JSON.stringify(req.headers));
            res.end();
    });

    module.exports = router;
```

Try this, It may work.